# Manipulating with SQL query output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to write a query which returns the month only in 3 characters but the first character should be Capital and the rest non-capital. For example DEC should be (Dec) or JAN (Jan).

```
select substr(sysdate,4,3) from dual;
```

SQL code above returns the month but in capital "DEC", so I want the output as "Dec".

Does anyone know how to achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `substr` on a DATE column. That relies on the evil implicit data type conversion. On my computer your query would return `8-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work indeed jus to use an extra function   that is initials with caps on :

```
select initcap(substr(sysdate,4,3)) from dual;
```

Comment: Don't use `substr` on a DATE column. That relies on the evil implicit data type conversion. On my computer this would return `8-1`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for manipulation, as stated in previous answers.

You can simply write this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'Mon', 'nls_date_language=American') FROM DUAL;
```

If you'd pass 'Month' as the second parameter you'd get 'December', if you'd pass 'month' you'd get 'december' and if you pass 'Mon' you will get 'Dec', as you have asked.

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `substr` with `to_char` function.

```
select substr(to_char(sysdate, 'Month', 'nls_date_language=American') ,0,3)  from dual
```

[c# online](https://rextester.com/UBP5783)

**Note**

use `nls_date_language=American` to set culture in `to_char` function.